Draw a part of a sphere
I am trying to draw the following:
(x-1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2, x <= 0

which is a part of the sphere with center (1, 0, 0) and radius square root of 2. In fact, what I really want is that with center (cos pi/4, sin pi/4, 0) (so that the cutting plane is accordingly rotated, keeps containing (0, 0, 0)). But I may start with a simpler one.
Below is an illustration:

Below is an MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1, 0, 0) circle (1.4142); \shade[ball color=blue, opacity=0.5] (1, 0) circle (1.4142);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Could you show, how it should look like at the end?

So you want half of a sphere?  Note that a plane is determined by three points.  In your comment, you are talking only about two: the center and the origin.  You can find a sphere on the site constructed from small quadrilaterals or triangles.  You take half of them...

@cis Thanks for the comments. A picture is added for illustration. In fact my previous description was wrong.

Like this:

Code:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
        \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(3,0) node[right] () {$x$} ;
        \draw[-latex] (0,-2)--(0,2) node[above] () {$y$};
        \fill (1,0) circle(1pt) node[below] () {(1,0,0)};
        \draw[blue!20] (1,0) circle(1.5);
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (-1,-2) rectangle (0,2);
        \fill[blue!60,opacity=.3] (1,0) circle(1.5);
        \end{scope}
        \fill[blue,opacity=.5] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=.15, y radius=1.085];
        \draw[dotted] (-.5,0)--(0,0);
        \draw (-1,0)--(-.5,0);
        \draw[-latex] (.5,1)--(-1,-2) node[below] () {$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}


Thank you for your answer! Would it be possible to make the object "more 3D"? I plan to create several of these shapes and have them intersect with each other.

Moreover, the object I want is not a "volume", it is just a "shell". You can see the difference by the x-axes.

@Salomo, how can you illustrate the shellish character of the object besides replacing the dark blue area by a thin rim?

@Salomo, I personally use tikz-3dplot, but other softwares include Asymptote and POV-Ray, etc. I did something similar here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726492/319072. To modify it will require learning tikz-3dplot, but I don't know another way if your goal is to draw them intersecting.
